# Как установить SQLite?

Tags: php, sqlite

Изучаю PHP, на компьютере установлено только MySQL + PHPMyAdmin. Что делать, чтобы перейти к работе с SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `php.ini` раскомментируйте

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.*
```

для работы через PDO, и, собственно, готово.

Если же у вас PHP < 5.3 , то ещё нужно раскомментировать

```
extension=php_pdo.*
```

Если работа с PHP происходит через `mod_php` для Apache, для вступления изменений в силу нужно будет перезапустить Apache.